Fullscreen API is preventing scroll
I'm creating a website in html, css and js that has a fullscreen function. Within this website I have a navigation bar that is changing the content displayed with innerHTML. The issue I'm facing is the absence of scrolling. Some places allows it, some places does not. I'm guessing that it is the size change of innerHTML is causing this.
function toggleFullscreen(){
    body.requestFullscreen();
}

function stickyNav() {
  document.querySelector("nav").innerHTML = `
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-home nav-box fullscreen" onclick="RenderOptions()">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
        <p class="nav-icon-name text-home"></p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-suspects nav-box fullscreen" onclick="RenderSuspects()">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i>
        <p class="nav-icon-name text-suspects"></p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-map nav-box" onclick="renderCurrentLocationView()">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-map"></i>
        <p class="nav-icon-name text-home"></p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-clues nav-box fullscreen" onclick="RenderClues()">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-clipboard-question"></i>
        <p class="nav-icon-name text-clue"></p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-arrest nav-box fullscreen" onclick="RenderMakeArrest()">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-handcuffs"></i>
        <p class="nav-icon-name text-arrest"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `;

  document.querySelectorAll(".fullscreen").forEach(box => {
    box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      toggleFullscreen();
    })
  });
}

I did try adding this in my CSS file

body {
  overflow: auto; /* or overflow: scroll; */
}

Any idea why I'm facing this issue?

Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Thanks for adding more to the question, but please do read through the inked article. What you've added isn't an MRE, although it could be part of one.

* linked article, oops
